# Getting error on google play console even setting Exported to true In AndroidManifest File

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

I am getting the following error while uploading to the google play console.

> You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle which has an activity, activity alias, service or broadcast receiver with intent filter, but without 'android: exported' property set. This file can't be installed on Android 12 or higher. See: developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported

I have set android:exported=true in the AndroidMenifest file.

This same file is working on other projects. Those projects are published successfully on the google play console. But not understanding the problem with this one.

here is my full AndroidManifest code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.*****">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <application
        android:exported="true"
        android:name="com.**"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <activity
            android:name="****.CalenderView"
            android:exported="true" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AD_MANAGER_APP"
            android:value="true" />

        <activity
            android:name="****.LoginActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:exported="true"
            android:name="****.UserWelcome"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_user_welcome"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:exported="true"
            android:name="*****.unitTest.UniteTest"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_user_welcome"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <meta-data android:name="applovin.sdk.key"
            android:value="****"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add exported only  with activity,  service  or receiver which have intent filters.

For the libraries that you are using for those also you need to define exported value.

Check this article for more details
https://cafonsomota.medium.com/android-12-dont-forget-to-set-android-exported-on-your-activities-services-and-receivers-3bee33f37beb